# Assign traffic volume to detailed road map in arcGIS

Tags: arcgis

I have two shapefiles. One is a street map with traffic volume data, another one is a detailed street map (accurate map) without traffic volumes.

when I compare the street map with traffic volume data with the detailed street map without traffic volume, lots of streets in the traffic volume data map do not align well with the actual streets, e.g., streets are straight lines when they should be curves.

I want to assign traffic volumes to streets in the accurate street map.

I have tried this:

a. transform the traffic volume data from polyline to points;

b. spatially join the points of traffic volume to the detailed street map.

This obviously doesn't work because when I join traffic volume points to the accurate street map, some streets have more than one points with different traffic volumes...

How can I approach this problem?
Any suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of doing transportation analysis, instead of convert road segment to point you may want to look at using linear reference model to handle this.
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm
That would solved your problem for multiple data points for one street.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it today!!

Comment: Hey Teng, sorry for bothering you again. I have looked into use linear reference model but I don't think it applies to my problem... Could you elaborate a little bit about how you would tackle the problem if you were me? Thank you so much!